# Kubernetes Network policies and traffic

Tags: kubernetes

I have two pods running within the same namespace there is no connection between then, however I want pod A to permit ingress & egress communication with pod B, I can not modify any of the objects that already exist, or create a new one. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Default is allow everywhere. What is preventing connection between these two pods ?

Comment: There are network policies already created but cannot be modified

Comment: If you have NetworkPolicies blocking your traffic AND you can't modify them then you have no options.

Comment: can you create networkpolicy ? by default if there arre no no network policies they should be able to communicate to each other.if there are some networkpolicies blocking the traffic between those pods then we need to either create a new network policy or edit the existing network policy to allow the traffic between those pods.

Comment: If you cannot create or edit anything, what could you possibly do? Effectively you cannot change the system at all. So you have to accept the way it's currently configured.

Answer (score 0):

Posted community wiki based on comments for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

---

Short answer: you can not do that without editing or creating new objects.

The recommended and supported way to control traffic flow in Kubernetes are [Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/). You already have them configured in a cluster, so you must edit them or create a new policy to change a traffic flow. Check also this - [Kubernetes Network Policy Recipes](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes).